# Chrome не видит "font-stretch: condensed;"

Tags: css

Как можно исправить?

Comment: Не рассматривали вариант использования шрифта narrow-начертания? http://www.fontsquirrel.com/fonts/list/keyword/narrow

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18752793/why-is-font-stretchcondensed-an-invalid-property-value-in-google-chrome

Answer (score 1):

Это свойство поддерживается только в IE 9+ и Firefox 9+.

[font-stretch](http://htmlbook.ru/css/font-stretch).

Comment: а есть ли какой нибудь способ сделать такой же эффект в хроме?

Comment: ну или как можно прописать стиль исключительно для хрома

Comment: http://hashcode.ru/questions/141716/css-%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%BD%D0%BE-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BB%D1%8C-%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%BB%D1%8E%D1%87%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%BE-%D0%B4%D0%BB%D1%8F-google-chrome